# Using a custom MailChimp UNSUB link

Tags: mailchimp

Is it possible to provide a value for *|UNSUB|* directing the audience to our own unsubscribe web service.

I have a mandate to not store the subscriber list on MailChimp but rather upload it when required.  The reader of the email would then click the unsubscribe link and be directed to our own unsubscription service.

I know this may sound unconventional, I am really just looking to see if this is an option or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible for the obvious reason: MailChimp (and any other worthwhile ESP) needs to be able to ensure you're not spamming people, so if someone requests to be removed from the list, MailChimp will need to remove them.

If you're not permitted to store the list at an ESP, you'll probably need to roll your own newsletter service rather than using a SaaS product.